# Best practice to prevent further instantiation of java classes

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I have some class storing keys with important information. No one else **is allowed** to create a key, since a key relys on static information (like certain directory structures etc.).

```
public final class KeyConstants
{

    private KeyConstants()
    {
        // could throw an exception to prevent instantiation
    }

    public static final Key<MyClass> MY_CLASS_DATA = new Key<MyClass>("someId", MyClass.class);

    public static class Key<T>
    {
        public final String ID;
        public final Class<T> CLAZZ;

        private Key(String id, Class<T> clazz)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.CLAZZ = clazz;
        }
    }

}
```

<sup>This example is simplyfied.</sup>

I wanted to test the consequences of a *wrong* key (exception handling, etc.) and instantiated the class via reflection in a JUnit test case.

```
Constructor<?> c = KeyConstants.Key.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, Class.class);
c.setAccessible(true);
@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
KeyConstants.Key<MyClass> r = (KeyConstants.Key<MyClass>) c.newInstance("wrongId", MyClass.class);
```

Then I asked myself how could I prevent further instantiation of the key class (i. e. preventing further object creating via reflection)?

`enums` came to my mind, but they don't work with generics.

```
public enum Key<T>
{
    //... Syntax error, enum declaration cannot have type parameters
}
```

**So how can I keep a set of `n` instances of a generic class and prevent further instantiation?**

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Are you just trying to prevent instantiation of "bad" copies of the class with invalid parameters? Are you trying to limit the total number ever created? Are you trying to ensure reuse of identical copies or otherwise "conserve" instances?

Comment: I want to provide a set of key instances, and theoretical users of the api shoud be able to use the instances, but shouldn't be able to create their own. Thats the problem I want to solve. It's more of a theoretical issue.

Comment: Why not use an `enum`?

Comment: Because enums don't work with generics, I already tried that.

Comment: This is screaming... [FACTORY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)!

Comment: I don't quite get that approach. Should the factory return a key-storing object, with all keys in it? The type `Key` has to be public for other classes to use it as a key. So there always will be the opportunity to instantiate it via reflection unless we change the instantiation mechanics of the class. Or how do you see it?

Comment: FYI. I've added another approach.

Answer (score 3):

> So how can I keep a set of n instances of a generic class and prevent
>   further instantiation?

If you truly want to use this pattern, then no one (including you) should be able to instantiate a `Key` object. In order to keep a set of n instances in a class with this pattern, you could have a private constructor, a static method for access and a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) to prevent reflection. And since you want to be able to access the keys as pubic constants, I would try something like this..

```
public class KeyConstants{

    // Here are your n instances for public access
    public static final int KEY_1 = 1;
    public static final int KEY_2 = 2;
    .
    .
    .
    public static final int KEY_N = 'n';


    // now you can call this method like this..
    // Key mKey = KeyConstants.getKey(KeyConstants.KEY_1);
    public static Key getKey(int key){

         List keys = Key.getInstances();

         switch(key){

         case KEY_1:
                     return keys.get(0);
         case KEY_2:
                     return keys.get(1);
         .
         .
         .
         case KEY_N:
                     return keys.get(n);
         default:
                     // not index out of bounds.. this means
                     // they didn't use a constant
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }

    }

    static class Key<T>{
        private static List<Key> instances;
        private String ID;
        private Class<T> CLAZZ;

        private Key(String id, Class<T> clazz){
                      this.ID = id;
                      this.CLAZZ = clazz;
         }

        public static List<Key> getInstances(){
            if(instances == null){

                            instances = new ArrayList<Key>();
                //populate instances list
            }

                    return instances;
        }
    }
}
```

Use `SecurityManager` to prevent reflection access.

```
//attempt to set your own security manager to prevent reflection
    try {
        System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager());
    } catch (SecurityException se) { 
    }

class MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        if (perm.getName().equals("suppressAccessChecks"))
            throw new SecurityException("Invalid Access");
    }

}
```

This will throw a `SecurityException` anytime someone attempts to access a private variable or field in your class (including access attempts via reflection).

Comment: Okay, that is an nice approach. But I also want to have handles to the keys. Any suggestions here. Maybe checking if `list.size() == numOfDesiredKeys` and then statically initializing a second class with `public static final Key<MyClass> KEY_1 = LIST.get(0);`

Comment: The `validConstruction` field can still be set to `true` using reflection.

Comment: Thx for the edit. I came across `SecurityManager` sometimes, but never had to use it. But still, how would you setup the handles to `Key`, the approach I posted in my former comment is not really clean.

Comment: +1 for `SecurityManager`. Is there a way to customize this manager only for some classes? I think of situation when we don't want to turn off `setAccessible` for entire project (we may need it somewhere) but only for lets say some package/class.

Comment: @Joel Hmm, it's pretty much the same as I suggested in my first commented. But I'm not sure if that's a good practice. I want the keys to be accessible via identifier in some place. How would you incorporate this into your approach?

Comment: @Mike Unless you know the number of Keys you have at compile time, you cannot really set up public final variables because you do not know how many you need. Your access options here are limited

Comment: Sry, if I did not make that clear enough. The number of keys is known at complime time, let's just say `x`. I used 1 in the example code in the question. So there should be just `x` keys, defined by one class/instance at complile time.

Comment: @mike see edit. Now you just need to call generateKeys() and you can access the keys by KeyConstants.KEY_1

Comment: @pshemo After pouring through the source code.. I could not find a good way for restricting this to only a few classes/packages.  The only thing I can think of would be to extend the AccessibleObject class and override methods in security manager to that the checkPermission() method knows the type of object requesting the permission.

Comment: Looks good! But I think `public static void generateKeys()` would be nicer in a static block. That's how I usually do it. If initialization takes to long, I add a static empty initialize method and call it during program initialization.

Comment: @mike Good call, that should save you some trouble and I doubt it will take long to initialize.  Edited post.

Comment: The example does **not** compile, if you do not remove the final modifiers on the key instances stored in KeyConstants (But then sb could still set the keys to `null`). Wouldn't it be best to just set the `SecurityManager` and leave the rest of the code?

Comment: Sorry about that.. Yes. That will guarantee that nothing except static Key methods can instantiate the class. I edited the post with another option if you like

Comment: Thx! But so far the best way to me seems to be using only a private constructor - as I showed it in the question - and adding an security manager. Or maybe redesigning so that there is no need for "generic enums", e. g. encapsulating the keys in the context in which they are needed (within a very small scope), or even using private classes.

Comment: @mike Whatever works best in your situation. Is there a reason you didn't accept my answer? Because I correctly answered your question by providing a way to prevent java class instantiation (via normal methods and reflection).

Comment: I understand that maybe there is no easy solution to my question due to JLS side restrictions, but I'm not sure, if I can consider your approach as a best practice for keeping a fixed set of instances of a generic class. I'm still hoping for input from more users. Maybe there is no satisfying solution, but I can't say that right now.

Comment: @mike "best practice for keeping a fixed set of instances of a generic class". First of all, that is a matter of opinion. Second, consider rereading your question.. because nowhere do you ask for the best practice for keeping a fixed set of instances. My answer is sufficient.

Comment: I'm sry, but I still have to say it is about the sentence you quoted. It's about finding a workaround for the need of having 'generic enums'. And I'm thankful for the approach you provided, but the key lies in the `SecurityManager`, which apparently can't be set just for certain scopes or classes. That is a solution, but not a best practice in my view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if a private constructor is not sufficient, can you use a more dynamic approach and throw an exception in the constructor after a signal is given?  For example:

```
public static class Key<T>
{
  private static boolean isLocked = false;

  // Call this method when you want no more keys to be created
  public static void lock() { isLocked = true; }

  ...

      private Key(String id, Class<T> clazz)
      {
          if (isLocked) throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create instances of Key");
          this.ID = id;
          this.CLAZZ = clazz;
      }
}
```

Then - and this is the disadvantage - you will have to call `Key.lock()` once you want to prevent more instances being created.

Comment: Of course if concerns about programmers using reflection is the problem, this won't help since the `isLocked` variable can still be modified.

Answer (score 1):

As you showed in your code to prevent instantiating `KeyConstants` you can throw some Exception inside private-non-argument constructor.

Harder part is way to block creating KeyConstants.Key constructor from outside of `KeyConstants` class.

### Some wild idea

Maybe create Exception in your constructor and check how its stack trace looks like. When I add this code to constructor

```
private Key(String id, Class<T> clazz) {

    StackTraceElement[] stack = new Exception().getStackTrace();
    for (int i=0; i<stack.length; i++){
        System.out.println(i+") "+stack[i]);
    }

    this.ID = id;
    this.CLAZZ = clazz;
}
```

and create instance of Key with reflection like

```
Constructor<?> c = KeyConstants.Key.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
        String.class, Class.class);
c.setAccessible(true);
KeyConstants.Key<MyClass> r = (KeyConstants.Key<MyClass>) c
        .newInstance("wrongId", MyClass.class);
```

I get

```
0) KeyConstants$Key.<init>(Test.java:38)
1) sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2) sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
3) sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
4) java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
```

so maybe just if 4th element of stack is `java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance` throw Exception to prevent executing rest of constructors code like:

```
if (stack.length>=4 && stack[4].toString().startsWith("java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance")){
    throw new RuntimeException("cant create object with reflection");
}
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that lines 0 - 3 are always the same regardless of the used JVM?

Comment: No, that is why it is wild idea. Also JVM can change the way/order of using these methods by adding new ones in the future releases so you would have to monitor it and update code when needed :/ (but this approach will do what you want - at least now on windows OS - so decided to post it)

Answer (score 1):

I came across some Multiton patterns recently, where I tried to handle problems with unique enum keys, that gave me the idea of another approach.

The keys can be used for information flow as I intended, or even as keys for typesafe heterogeneous container, where they can perform compile-time casting.

**Key-defining class**

```
public class KeyConstants
{

  public static final KeysForIntegers SOME_INT_KEY = KeysForIntegers.KEY_2;

  public static final KeysForStrings SOME_STRING_KEY = KeysForStrings.KEY_1;

  public interface Key<Type>
  {
    public Class<Type> getType();
  }

  /* Define methods that classes working with the keys expect from them */
  public interface KeyInformation
  {
    public String getInfo1();
    // and so on...
  }

  public enum KeysForStrings implements Key<String>, KeyInformation
  {
    KEY_1("someId");

    public final String ID;

    private KeysForStrings(String id)
    {
      ID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInfo1()
    {
      return "Good piece of information on " + ID + ".";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getType()
    {
      return String.class;
    }
  }

  public enum KeysForIntegers implements Key<Integer>, KeyInformation
  {
    KEY_2("bla");

    public final String ID;

    private KeysForIntegers(String id)
    {
      this.ID = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInfo1()
    {
      return "Some info on " + ID + ".";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Integer> getType()
    {
      return Integer.class;
    }
  }
}
```

**Example key-using class**

```
public class KeyUser
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    KeysForIntegers k1 = KeyConstants.SOME_INT_KEY;
    KeysForStrings k2 = KeyConstants.SOME_STRING_KEY;

    processStringKey(k2);
    useIntKey(k1);

    Integer i = useIntKey(KeyConstants.SOME_INT_KEY);
    processStringKey(KeyConstants.SOME_STRING_KEY);
  }

  /* My methods should just work with my keys */

  @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
  public static <TYPE, KEY extends Enum<KeysForIntegers> & Key<TYPE> & KeyInformation> TYPE useIntKey(KEY k)
  {
    System.out.println(k.getInfo1());
    return (TYPE) new Object();
  }

  public static <KEY extends Enum<KeysForStrings> & KeyInformation> void processStringKey(KEY k)
  {
    System.out.println(k.getInfo1());
    // process stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's just about processing, one could overload methods like `process(KeyForStrings k)`, `process(KeyForInetgers k)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have another approach, you can bound an interface in a way to only be implemented by `enum`.
With that approach you have a fixed set of instances at compile time.

If you want to add lazy loading, the enums implementing it should be proxies that load the desired object if it is requested. The class or classes that are hidden behind the proxies should only be visible to them, so that they have exclusive access to the constructor.

```
public class User {

  public static <S> S handleKey(FixedInstanceSet<S,?> key) {
    return key.getKey();
  }
}

interface FixedInstanceSet<S, T extends Enum<T> & FixedInstanceSet<S,T>>
{
  public S getKey();
}

enum StringKeys implements FixedInstanceSet<String, StringKeys> {
  TOP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
  @Override
  public String getKey() { return null; }
}

enum IntKeys implements FixedInstanceSet<Integer, IntKeys > {
  TOP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
  @Override
  public Integer getKey() { return null; }
}

/*
 * Bound mismatch: The type NotWorking is not a valid substitute for the bounded
 * parameter <T extends Enum<T> & FixedInstanceSet<S,T>> of the type
 * FixedInstanceSet<S,T>
 */
//class NotCompiling implements FixedInstanceSet<String, NotCompiling> {
//
//  @Override
//  public String getKey() { return null; }
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want your class to be instantiated.
You can set the default constructor to private

```
private Key() throws IllegalStateException //handle default constructor
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

This will prevent its improper instantiation.

Update:
added throw IllegalStateException

Comment: This alone will *not* prevent instantiation.

Comment: Could someone explain how this doesn't answer the question?  I'm not disagreeing, I just don't understand.

Comment: A private constructor can only be called within that class. This will not automatically prevent instantiation but it will prevent it being instantiated outside of class. The problem is solved if you do not intentionally create a new instance of your class within your class by calling `new Key();`

Comment: @Lai: You can still use reflection to create new instances, though (just like OP showed in the question).

Comment: So is the fact that reflection can be used to bypass the access modifier the only complaint?  I understand the concern, but surely you just work on the basis that if people try this, they are using unsupported code?  `private` is usually considered sufficient for other Java code.

Comment: @jazzbassrob Of course, this is more of an theoretical issue for me. `private` is sufficient for now. But I think this is a valid problem and I would like to know how to solve it.